# bashrc in opt/distra/bashrc changes are not reflecting permanently

Tags: bash, oraclelinux

I have my bashrc file in `/opt/distra/bashrc` and trying to add a path in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable but the changes are not reflecting after closing the terminal and re-starting and re starting the Linux Machine.

OS : Oracle Linux 7.7

My bashrc looks like this

```
# User specific environment variables 
export DISTRA_USER=$USER
export M2_HOME=/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.0.5
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
export BT3_HOME=/opt/distra/bt3
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/lib:/opt/distra/executive/current/lib:/opt/mqm/java/lib64
```

I am trying to add `:/opt/mqm/java/lib64` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable

I have to do `. /opt/distra/bashrc` everytime i start my machine. There must be some way that i am not aware of to make the change permanently.

What shall i do to make the changes permanent ?

Edit :

My .bashrc in home directory has the following lines:

```
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Source distra definitions
if [ -f /opt/distra/bashrc ]; then
        . /opt/distra/bashrc
fi
```

My .bash_profile in home directory has the following lines:

```
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$HOME/scripts
export PATH
```

Comment: @NlkhilRohilla : Why do you think that a file in `/opt/distra` should have any effect to your bash, and why did you tag this _mq_  and _oraclelinux_.

Comment: I was letting people know the OS and path to be set in variable is for mq

Comment: I don't see why this is relevant, but the real question is: What did you do to have bash process your /opt/distra/bashrc file?

Comment: I didnt do anything. Its just the way it was when i got the machine.

Comment: If someone sets up your machine in a particular way, how are we supposed what's going on? You certainly don't expect that some commands placed in some arbitrary file would magically have effect in your current shell. If you want to run these commands in your shell, you have to _source_ them, i.e. `source /opt/distra/bashrc`.

Comment: I dont think that sourcing the bashrc from anywhere makes any difference. This question is just about asking how to make the change in bashrc permanent so that when i re start my machine, i dont have to source from it every time.

Comment: You source it there where you need it. In your case, if you want the settings be executed for each interactive shell, source it from `~/.bashrc`. If you need it for each login shell, source it from `~/.bash_profile` (or whatever you use for login shells). If you need it be executed for a particular script of yours, source it from there.

Comment: As a side remark: Your approach to define `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is dangerous. Aside from the obvious errors pointed out in the answer by Tommy Reynolds, you have the problem that your definition replaces any existing definition for the library path instead of extending it. I would for the safe side first test for the existence of this variable, and if it exist already, append (or prepend) the new path definitions to the existing ones.

Comment: I have edited the question and put the .bashrc and .bash_profile lines sourcing the bashrc file

Comment: This approach should work, and whenever you create a new interactive bash shell, the variables will be set.  Note that PATH would be set in this way only for login shells. You can verify it by doing a `bash --login -i`.

Comment: This approach is also not working. The path still does not change and i have to exclusively source bashrc file.

Comment: Then you need to run a `bash --login -i -x` to find out, why the changes in your `~/.bash_profile` does not work. The approach by itself is correct, so you must have a bug in one of your startup files.

Answer (score 0):

The line "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/lib:/opt/distra/executive/current/lib**:/opt/mqm/java/lib64**"

looks bogus because: 1) LD_LIBRARY_PATH should contain only directory paths, not individual library archive paths; and 2) since this entry is unquoted, the shell wildcards "**" will be expanded; I don't think this is what you really want.  Try:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/lib:/opt/distra/executive/current/lib:/opt/mqm/java/lib64'

i.e., enclose the value in single quotes.  This really isn't necessary here but the single quotes will keep you safe from directories with embedded whitespace, not that you should actually use those on a Linux box.

Comment: Hi, i think there's some misunderstanding. I was trying to make the last part :/opt/distra/bashrc as bold but it appeared with quotes. I'll edit the question